# Ar metio build error

Tags: iphone, build, augmented-reality

When I'm trying to run the project i receive the following errors

Here is the log.

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:** `__ZN6metaio40getScreenRotationForInterfaceOrientationE22UIInterfaceOrientation", referenced from: -[MetaioSDKViewController viewDidLoad] in MetaioSDKViewController.o -[MetaioSDKViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] in MetaioSDKViewController.o -[ARELViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] in ARELViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Does any one knows what the reason might be.

This project has bind with the Metio . AR framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on your Project and go to **Build Settings** and change the value of **Build Active Architecture only** to **yes**.

Let me know if it solves the error:)

Comment: Check for any libraries or any files from sdk that are missing from build phases...for that go to Build Phases COmpile sources and make sure all the .m files are added their that exists in your project and if any of them missing add it

Comment: so are you trying to build on ios 5 and also did u check the compile sources

Comment: This is i have  Xcode 4.3.1 . if  i run on this . then this will be the error. but if i run on Xcode. 4.3.2 . thn thr is no compile runs perfectly

Comment: hmm mine works well and i am on xcode 4.5.1 and im building on ios6 sdk..im not sure of this error..but as soon as i get to know..will get back to you